# Video speed variable doesn't reset, but previous effect is also not taking place?

Tags: jquery, performance, video

We are using hapyak to load our video playlists. We added custom speed buttons that allow a user to increase or decrease playback speed.

**Slower** (clicking 1 time will slow down the video 5%, slowest being 80% from 100%).

**Normal** on click returns the video to 100%.

**Faster** Same as slower, but goes fast, max is 150%.

Basically what is happening is when the video changes (no page reload) the buttons stay at their current number (usually 150%), but the effects are not present on the video. Clicking the play faster button will do nothing, but if you click "play slower" to drop it to 145%, then click back to play faster, it will continue the video at 150% pace.

Is there a way I can get both the speed variable AND it's effect to carry over throughout the playlist?

```
  var currentSpeed = 1;
  var fadeout_timer = setTimeout(function() {
    $( "#videoSpeed" ).fadeOut();
  }, 1600);

  function updateSpeed() {
    document.getElementById("videoSpeedCounter").innerHTML = (Math.round(currentSpeed * 100)) + "%";

    if ($("#videoSpeed").is(":hidden")) {
      $( "#videoSpeed" ).fadeIn();
    }

    // Fade out after 1600ms from last click -- clearTimeout resets the fadeout timer.
    clearTimeout(fadeout_timer);

    fadeout_timer = setTimeout(function() {
      $( "#videoSpeed" ).fadeOut();
    }, 1600);
    return false;

  }

  function speedIncrease() {
    if (currentSpeed < 1.50) {
      currentSpeed = currentSpeed + 0.05;
      hapyak.playlist.get()._player.playbackRate(currentSpeed);
      updateSpeed();
    }
    return false;
  }

  function speedDecrease() {
    if (currentSpeed > .8) {
      currentSpeed = currentSpeed - 0.05;
      hapyak.playlist.get()._player.playbackRate(currentSpeed);
      updateSpeed();
    }
    return false;
  }

  function resetSpeed() {
    currentSpeed = 1;
    hapyak.playlist.get()._player.playbackRate(currentSpeed);
    updateSpeed();
  }

  function nextVideo() {
      currentSpeed = currentSpeed
      hapyak.playlist.get()._player.playbackRate(currentSpeed);

  }

  var hapyakPlaylist = hapyak.playlist.get();
  console.log("Playlists: " + hapyakPlaylist);
```

Theoretically, I believe I just need a way to have it save out `currentSpeed` so it doesn't reset at the beginning.

```
<div class="video-speed-buttons-container">
  <a onclick="speedDecrease()"><div class="video-speed-button first">Play slower</div></a>
  <a onclick="resetSpeed()"><div class="video-speed-button">Normal speed</div></a>
  <a onclick="speedIncrease()"><div class="video-speed-button">Play faster</div></a>
  <div class="video-speedometer" id="videoSpeed">Speed: <span id="videoSpeedCounter">100%</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is Kyle from HapYak. The HapYak Viewer object holds a reference to the player where the playbackRate is set. When you change to a different video the Viewer object is destroyed and a new instance setup for the newly loaded video. What you'll need to do is get a reference to the current Viewer object, and reset the playbackRate any time a different video in the playlist is played.

You can get a reference from the hapyak.instances.viewer collection.

If you send me a link to your page / implementation I can try to help with a more concrete example.